# Merge external dlls and class library dll in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, dll, class-library

I have implemented dll using class library c# with externel dlls like `Desharp.dll`, `Newtonsoft.Json.dll`, `System.Net.Http.Formatting.dll`.
I want single dll of above all dll merge because when i need use my dll no need to add that externel dlls.

=>below link i have saved my required dlls of releced my class library project c#
https://files.fm/u/bccxanhz

Answer (score -1):

In this blogpost three methods to achieve this are described: http://www.manuelmeyer.net/2016/01/net-power-tip-10-merging-assemblies/

They fall into two categories:

1. Merge all assemblies into one. For this, the tool ILMerge is available.
2. Include the external assemblies as resources (build action "Embedded Reosurce") in your assembly and handle the `AppDomain.AssemblyResolve` event to load the requested assembly from the resource (using `Assembly.GetManifestResourceStream()`).